# Kotlin; find an object in a LiveData by id

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm a newby in kotlin. I have a LiveData of List of User object  which is like below:

```
data class User(id: String, userName: String, name: String)
```

I need to find just one object which has userName of "xxxx". I tried this code:

```
user = userViewModel.allUsers.value!!.find{ it.userName == userName}
```

But it didn't work

UserViewModel is as below:

```
class UserViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var parentJob = Job()
    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    private val repository: UserRepository
    val allUsers: LiveData<List<User>>

    init {
        val usersDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, scope).userDao()
        repository = UserRepository(usersDao)
        allUsers = repository.allUsers
    }

    fun getByUserName(userName: String)  = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.findUserById(userName)
    }

    fun insert(user: User) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(user)
    }
    fun update(user: User) = scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.update(user)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        parentJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: check [find](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) method

Comment: Yes I found it. I need a sample though.

Comment: `myList.find{ it.userName == "xxxx" }`

Comment: I updated my question. I still have the same problem

Comment: `find` should work. Just check whether the User with the name you are searching is in the list. Or maybe you should search by `name`: `.find{ it.name == userName}`

Comment: Again it didn't work. Maybe the problem is in the LiveData.

Comment: You're supposed to `observe` it, not `.value` it

Comment: Actually, this is tricky; you should have added Repository code and possibly DAO code in order to answer this.

Comment: Actually I used blockingFirst() method with Flowable and it did work

Comment: You can't call viewmodel.value , use below code viewmodel. allUsers.observe(this, Observer) { it. userName == userName}